# Need to know how to format a Numeric Column into 12 digits and put in format xxxx_xxxx_xxxx

Tags: r

Using R, Need to know how to format a column to 12 digits and the format it to xxxx_xxxx_xxxx.

```
#install.packages("tidyr")
#install.packages("readxl")
library(tidyr)
library(readxl)

projectToL4Raw <- read.csv("project_pro.csv")
projectToL4Raw
projectToL4RawSeparator <- separate(projectToL4Raw, ALLOCATION_CBD, c("CBD", "Cost Center"), sep = ":")

write.csv(projectToL4RawSeparator, file = "my_data.csv")
```

I have imported a file which has column with number `'10021502'`. Need to format the column to `000010021502` and then to `0000_1002_1502`.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
x <- '10021502'
```

we can use `formatC` to get desired output

```
formatC(
  x = as.integer(x),
  width = 12,        # total width
  flag = "0",        # pads zeros at beginning
  big.mark = "_",    # mark between every big.interval before the decimal point
  big.interval = 4   # see above
)
# [1] "0000_1002_1502"
```

Comment: How one can manage with a 12 digits string, for instance `x - "123456789123"`?

Comment: @ANG Good question. What would be desired output? But don't think this is relevant for OP as they write they need 'to format a column to 12 digits'.

Comment: The output must be `x` itself i.e. `123456789123`. I guess that if OP wants _to format a column to 12 digits_ it should relevant to consider that the column has strings lower or equal to 12 digits. The aim being to make the column homogeneous

Comment: Thanks for your response. While executing the code on my data, I am getting Warning message as Warning message:
In formatC(x = as.numeric(projectToL4RawSeparator$CBD), width = 12,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: Please let me know if I am missing something

Comment: @PinakiDutta Hard to say without sample data. Can you share the output of `dput(head(projectToL4RawSeparator$CBD, 20))` at the end of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
x <- '10021502'
```

The following will do the trick

```
gsub("([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})", "0000_\\1_\\2", x)
```